# Python unit test failure: should raise value error but not

Tags: python, unit-testing, raiserror

Here is my code trying to learn unit testing. 
Create a Student class for the purpose of testing. The test invalid test case constantly failed.

```
FAIL: test_invalid (__main__.TestStudent)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mystudent.py", line 46, in test_invalid
    s1.get_grade()
AssertionError: ValueError not raised
```

above is from running result.

Could anyone help me to figure out why I have this failure while I think I have put the right 'Raise Error' code there....

```
import unittest

class Student(object):
def __init__(self, name, score):
    self.name = name
    self.score = score


def get_grade(self):
    try:
        if self.score >= 60 and self.score < 80:
            return 'B'
        if self.score >= 80 and self.score <= 100:
            return 'A'
        if self.score >= 0 and self.score <60:
            return 'C'
        if self.score < 0 or self.score > 100:
            raise ValueError('Invalid score value')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Value error!')


class TestStudent(unittest.TestCase):


def test_invalid(self):
    s1 = Student('Bob', -1)
    s2 = Student('Bat', 101)
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
        s1.get_grade()
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
        s2.get_grade()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Thanks

Comment: Your function *doesn't* raise ValueError. Code within the function does raise that exception, but then catches it and deals with it. The function as a whole does not raise the exception.

Comment: Thanks! got it. Thanks for helping with editing my question also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're catching the `ValueError` inside the function. You need to either remove the `try`/`except` block in the function or re-`raise` it after doing whatever you want inside:

```
def get_grade(self):
    try:
        if self.score >= 60 and self.score < 80:
            return 'B'
        if self.score >= 80 and self.score <= 100:
            return 'A'
        if self.score >= 0 and self.score <60:
            return 'C'
        if self.score < 0 or self.score > 100:
            raise ValueError('Invalid score value')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Value error!') 
        raise  # Passes the exception up
```

Comment: Yeah, I removed the try/except block and the unit test case passed.